# TypeScript insert record to multi dimension array ( Eg - Array< number | [number, number] | [string, number] )>

Tags: angular, typescript, multidimensional-array, highcharts

I am using 'angular-highcharts' in one of component files. so have created a array like bellow in angular component.ts file. which will store data and draw a high chart (stock) in the html view page.

```
public myData : Array< number | [number, number] | [string, number]>;
```

when i tried to push data into it

```
this.myData.push(12540 ,2488);
```

it compiles correctly, but getting bellow at the runtime.

```
core.js:1624 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
at third-page.component.ts:136
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at SafeSubscriber._next (third-page.component.ts:118)
at
```

any idea ? what is the best way to insert data into this mydata array and bind to chart ?

Comment: you need to init the array: `public myData : Array< number | [number, number] | [string, number]> = [];`

Comment: yes, its working. Thanks!, now the problem is when i push data into array like this 

this.myData.push(12540 ,2488);

its not adding them into correct way, seems they are adding one after another.

Answer (score 4):

You need to instantiate the array. Try:

```
public myData : Array< number | [number, number] | [string, number]> = [];
```

Comment: Instantiation can also be performed inside constructor